# In bootstrap, how to enlarge one of these images when mouse is hovered? And IE8 shall be compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make the effects with following:

1. Bootstrap is applied.
2. When mouse is hovered on one of these image, the images shall be enlarged.
3. The enlarge effect shall on all borders, not one or two borders enlarged but the others remain as the same.
4. The enlarged image position doesn't move.
5. Other images doesn't get effected.

   ```
   <div id="Frame" class="FrameClass">
   <table id="FrameTable" class="table">
       <tr>
           <td><a><img class="img-responsive img-rounded"style="position:absolute; max-width:268px;" src="img/1.png" alt="1"/></a></td>
           <td><a><img class="img-responsive img-rounded"style="position:absolute; max-width:268px;" src="img/2.png" alt="2"/></a></td>
           <td><a><img class="img-responsive img-rounded"style="position:absolute; max-width:268px;" src="img/3.png" alt="3"/></a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><a><img class="img-responsive img-rounded"style="position:absolute; margin-top:170px;" src="img/4.png" alt="4"/></a></td>
           <td><a><img class="img-responsive img-rounded"style="position:absolute; margin-top:170px;" src="img/5.png" alt="5"/></a></td>
           <td><a><img class="img-responsive img-rounded"style="position:absolute; margin-top:170px;" src="img/6.png" alt="6"/></a></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```

Comment: You should show your attempts at doing the above and the specifically where you were having issues

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern mate, I'm using the Bootstrap in my little webpage, and now I got 6 images in my table, the effect I'd like to implement is that when mouse is hovering on the image, the image shall be enlarged, do you know how to do that? Again, thank you very much!

Comment: have you considered taking a look at `:hover` selector and the `transform` CSS property?