# How to enlarge images on hover using only CSS in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now, a user could download and see images using Ruby on Rails. 
I would like that those images be enlarged on hover.

The similar question was asked (link below) without the answer on it.

[In bootstrap, how to enlarge one of these images when mouse is hovered? And IE8 shall be compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814446/in-bootstrap-how-to-enlarge-one-of-these-images-when-mouse-is-hovered-and-ie8)

To implement this functionality, I’ve added :hover to custom.scss(see below)  but the pictures want not being enlarged on hover.

```
span.picture {
    margin-top: 10px;
    input {
      border: 0;
    }
  }
   span.picture:hover {
     transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

//The files related are similar as below:

'''from source/bootstrap'''

```
    <span class="content">
        pic
        <img src="https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/micropost/picture/124/1.JPG" alt="B1" />
      </span>
```

'''from custom.scss'''

```
.content {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 60px;
    img {
      display: block;
      padding: 5px 0;
    }
  }


span.picture {
  margin-top: 10px;
  input {
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

'''from Gemfile'''

```
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
```

Comment: Your `span` tag does not have a `picture` class. Maybe you want to use `span.content img` as the selector instead of `span.picture`.

Comment: I've used all classes from Michael Hartl  tutorial as is. If I change something, I need to change something else regarding.  Could you answer on my question and show what  changes need to be done to   enlarge images on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you are showing the CSS should be:

```
.content {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  img {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
  }
}
.content:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

I have no idea what's that `span.picture` selector for, at least there's no span element with class picture on the HTML you are showing.

Comment: It is working for one app. but not for others. I need to figure out why is the difference. 
thanks .